# Selecting entire string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with a regex to select this entire string
%2526_ga%253d1.193373933.1506621463.1391436765&

this exact match is always there: 
%2526_ga%253d

there's always a random number like this, but don't focus on the period since there's other periods later in the URL similar to this:
1.193373933.1506621463.1391436765&

This is what I have so far:

```
var str = window.location.search.match('_ga%253d');
alert(str);
```

Comment: can the number part be any length or does it have the same amount of digits between periods every time? Does it always end with a `&`?

Comment: that's a good question. I'll have to test and check a couple times to see if the length of the number changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your prefix plus any digits full stops until the first etcetera the regex below should do

```
/_ga%253d'([0-9\.])+&/
```